# Navigation Bar is not aligned to top most edge

Tags: ios, swift, navigationbar

How do I remove the gap between top edge and navigation bar?

[image: Arrow Mark represents gap.]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read the guidelines for how to post a good question. Make sure to describe the problem in-depth. What are you trying to do exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of two navigation controllers in the flow chart. Nav Controller 1 -> Tab View Controller -> Nav Controller 2 -> View Controller.

Answer (score 0):

Set property of UIViewController in storyborard using following screenshot.

[image]

Comment: I am using "inferred" for all the view controllers from the beginning. I never changed it to other than Inferred.

Comment: check once with select another options like  Translucent Navigation Bar .

Comment: I cheked with all the top bar options. It is not helping.